# React onChange to handle state objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an interesting question regarding React state and onChange events in the form.  In my React component, I am storing information in the state, that includes objects.  When a user types in a change, I would like part of that object in the state to change.  As an example, here is the state I am talking about:

```
this.state = {
      total: 0,
      email: '',
      creditCards: [],
      selectedCreditCard: {},
      billingAddresses: [],
      shippingAddresses: [],
      selectedBillingAddress: {},
      selectedShippingAddress: {},
    }
```

This is the state of the component, and this is my handle change function:

```
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    })
  }
```

As you can probably tell, this type of function will not work for objects within the state.  As an example, when a user types in their credit card number, I would like this.state.selectedCreditCard.creditCardNumber to be the thing that changes.  Of course, with the way it is setup in my form:

```
<input
          type="text"
          name="selectedCreditCard.creditCardNumber"
          value={selectedCreditCard.creditCardNumber}
          onChange={(evt) => handleChange(evt)}
        />
```

The "name" being passed into the onChange is only a string, and not a pointer to a key value in one of the objects in the state.  Therefore, there is no easy way for this function to work except for deconstructing each object in the state and placing every key:value directly in the state instead of within the object; doing this is a possibility, but the code becomes very cumbersome this way.  I hope all of this makes sense.  Is there any way to manipulate the objects within the state, and have the form pass a pointer to a key in the object, as opposed to a string?  Thanks.

Comment: This is an off topic question but is there a reason you are using React class components instead of easier React hooks?

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that the "outer" component is a class component which holds the state.  The form is its own functional component in which the state is passed down into it as props.  Truthfully, I am not using hooks because I do not have as good of an understanding of them just yet, although I do plan to learn more about them in the future.

Comment: Its been such a long time since I stopped using React class components that I forgot setState's features without doing some research. I could help with React hooks.

Comment: So, you think using React hooks would make this process easier for me?

Comment: Regarding React in general, yes. You will likely have to learn React hooks since they "may" deprecate it the future and most modern implementations use React hooks. Regarding your example, you would just make a custom handleChange specifically to update the selectedCreditCard.

Comment: @SILENT Even with functional components and react hooks it would be much the same process. OP has to either create separate handlers for the differently nested state (would be exactly the same with a single `useState` hook), or convert to functional component and use a separate `useState` hook for each state chunk which *still* requires separate state update handlers. The main issue here is OP doesn't have a flat form field state structure. Zerst, is there a compelling reason for the nesting?

Comment: The only compelling reason really is that it "looks" cleaner, and also the state is set initially in the componentDidMount, and the object (which comes from a redux axios request) that sets the state is structured with nested objects, that is my main reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand from your description that you wish to update a nested child inside a state object attribute like below

```js
//default state
this.state = {
      total: 0,
      email: '',
      creditCards: [],
      selectedCreditCard: {},
      billingAddresses: [],
      shippingAddresses: [],
      selectedBillingAddress: {},
      selectedShippingAddress: {},
    }
```

to be updated to something like this

```js
//state after handleEvent
{
      total: 0,
      email: '',
      creditCards: [],
      selectedCreditCard:{
       creditCardNumber:"102131313"
      }, 
      billingAddresses: [],
      shippingAddresses: [],
      selectedBillingAddress: {},
      selectedShippingAddress: {},
 }
```

If thats the case.
Here's a recursion based solution to create a nested object using a **"."** based name string.

```
  handleChange(event) {
    //use split function to create hierarchy. example:
    //selectedCreditCard.creditCardNumber -> [selectedCreditCard , creditCardNumber]
    const obj = this.generate(
      event.target.name.split("."),
      event.target.value,
      0
    );
    
    this.setState({ ...obj });
  }

  //use recursion to generate nested object. example
  //([selectedCreditCard , creditCardNumber] , 12 , 0) -> {"selectedCreditCard":{"creditCardNumber":"12"}} 
  generate(arr, value, index) {
    return {
      [arr[index]]:
        index === arr.length - 1 ? value : this.generate(arr, value, index + 1)
    };
  }
```

I have created a codesandbox demo for you to explore more here.
[demo-link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-moon-n9kiv?file=/src/App.js:470-1099)

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540162/unable-to-fetch-a-field-from-a-table-in-react/77540481?noredirect=1#comment136699940_77540481